# Code issue - opening subsite

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a code where I want to debug that why it cannot open the subsite, however in quickwatch window it opens it fine by doing "site.openweb(str[1])"

My code below (where str[0] has the server name and str[1] has subsite name):

```
SPWeb spwebdest = null;
            SPSite site = null;
            try
            {
                SPListItem spitem = workflowProperties.Item;
                string[] str = workflowProperties.AssociationData.Split(',');
                string Listtitle = spitem.ParentList.Title;


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str[1]))
                {
                    spwebdest = new SPSite("http://" + str[0]).OpenWeb(str[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    site = new SPSite("http://" + str[0]);
                    spwebdest = site.RootWeb;
                }


                SPList list = spwebdest.Lists[str[2]];
                SPListItemCollection itemcoll = list.GetItems(new SPQuery()
                {
                    Query = @"<Where>
                <Eq>
                   <FieldRef Name='Title' />
                   <Value Type='Text'>" + spitem.Title + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
                });
```

Need help

Thanks.

Comment: what exception you get?

Comment: could you elaborate on the 3 lines of your code at  the beginning of the 'try' block - regarding 'workflowProperties' ?

Comment: I m writing a custom workflow

Comment: Getting no exception just the open web line isnt getting hit

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your str[1] value is an empty string.

If you are able to the use the 'site' object then you're getting into the 'else' portion of your if statement. That's only place it's being set.

Calling SPSite.OpenWeb() with an empty string, site.OpenWeb(""), will still give you the root web.

I would take at what is contained in your str array after you split the AssociationData.

Comment: It contains comma seperated values like e.g: servername, subsitename, listname

Comment: I have checked it by debugging the code, the value in str[1] is the subsites name and in quick watch it works fine but while debugging I can see that when it reaches the breakpoint of site.OpenWeb(str[1]) it just skips that line and moves to the code below it.

Answer (score 0):

you have open the subsite from created site.

from the above example you have to write the code as

SPSite spwebdest=null;
SPWeb currentWeb=null;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str[0])) 
{ 
    spwebdest = new SPSite("http://" + str[0]);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(str[1]))
    {
        currentWeb=spwebdest.OpenWeb(str[1]))
    }
}

if it not worked you have to check string values giving corrct url or not.

Simple Suggestion: When ever you are opening a site or web you have to dispose them after using them. you have to use "Using" or "spsite.Dispose()"